# Flutter Error: You must specify a URL a Maven repository

Tags: android, maven, gradle, flutter, androidx

In my project I developed with flutter, I get the following error. I got this error all of a sudden. Normally my project was running, I didn't change anything and I started getting this error.

I have listed the error output and images of my files below. Where am I doing wrong or why am I getting this error, can you help?

#### Error

[image: Error]

#### gradle.properties

[image: gradle.properties]

#### app/build.gradle 1 of 2

[image: app/build.gradle - 1]

#### app/build.gradle 2 of 2

[image: app/build.gradle - 2]

#### build.gradle

[image: build.gradle]

**Edit**

*Detail*

```
2020-03-06T21:42:06.164+0300 [DEBUG] 
[org.gradle.internal.resources.AbstractTrackedResourceLock] Daemon 
worker Thread 7: released lock on root.1
2020-03-06T21:42:06.164+0300 [ERROR] 
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
2020-03-06T21:42:06.164+0300 [ERROR]         
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
2020-03-06T21:42:06.164+0300 [ERROR] 
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
2020-03-06T21:42:06.164+0300 [ERROR] 
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went 
 wrong:
2020-03-06T21:42:06.164+0300 [ERROR] 
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Could not 
determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileProfileJavaWithJavac'.
2020-03-06T21:42:06.164+0300 [ERROR] 
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] > You must 
specify a URL for a Maven repository.
2020-03-06T21:42:06.164+0300 [ERROR] 
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
2020-03-06T21:42:06.164+0300 [ERROR] 
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Try:
2020-03-06T21:42:06.164+0300 [ERROR] 
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Run with -- 
stacktrace option to get the stack trace.  Run with --scan to get full 
insights.
2020-03-06T21:42:06.164+0300 [ERROR] 
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
2020-03-06T21:42:06.164+0300 [ERROR] 
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Get more 
 help at https://help.gradle.org
 2020-03-06T21:42:06.164+0300 [WARN] 
[org.gradle.internal.featurelifecycle.LoggingDeprecatedFeatureHandler] 
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it 
incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See 





2020-03-06T21:42:06.165+0300 [ERROR] 
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger] 
2020-03-06T21:42:06.165+0300 [ERROR] 
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger] BUILD FAILED in 6s
2020-03-06T21:42:06.165+0300 [DEBUG] 
[org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] 
Completing Build operation 'Run build'
2020-03-06T21:42:06.165+0300 [DEBUG] 
[org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build 
operation 'Run build' completed
2020-03-06T21:42:06.168+0300 [DEBUG]
```

Comment: Always post text when you can. Don't post images. Read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Comment: Now about your error, Are you behind some proxy network?

Comment: Also stacktrace is more important than the error so always post full stacktrace

Comment: yes, but i also tried it on my own network and with hotspot. It doesn't seem like a problem with the Internet.

Comment: The error mostly is for networks behind proxy. If you are using on hotspot verify that no proxy is set at system level and at gradle level or at environment variable level. Also if you were using ethernet disconnect/disable the ethernet.

Comment: ./gradlew --stacktrace result  https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDXMH.png

Comment: it looks successful but when I run it I get the same error again

Answer (score 0):

The maven repository wasn't added on your build.gradle file. It should look like this

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

If you have other issues on your Android folder, you can just simply delete the `/android` folder on your Flutter project and generate an Android build again by running `flutter create --platform=android [PROJECT_PATH]`